# Using multiple angular elements as web components within an angular project

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

Given three @angular projects all using v6.1.9: `host`, `alpha`, and `beta`

`alpha` and `beta` create and define a web component each using @angular/elements as such:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

ngDoBootstrap() {
  const config: NgElementConfig = { injector: this.injector };
  const component= createCustomElement(component, config);
  customElements.define("alpha-component", component); // beta-component respectively
}
```

`alpha` and `beta` are built using `ng build --prod --output-hashing none` and then a post build script is ran to concatenate the resulting files in the order of: `scripts.js, styles.js, runtime.js, main.js`.

polyfills.js is skipped because `main.ts` will check if the polyfills used are already defined when the library is loaded (to avoid trying to redefine zones.js for example).

The resultant bundles are `alpha-component.bundle.js` and `beta-component.bundle.js`.

`host` references the above bundles in the `<head>` of `index.html` with `<script defer>` tags.

If the bundles are referenced in the order of `alpha` then `beta`, I will see `alpha` trying to bootstrap twice; In the reverse order, I will see `beta` trying to bootstrap twice.

Since the first referenced bundle attempts to bootstrap twice, it attempts to define the web component for the bundle twice, causing an error, and never registering the second referenced bundle's web component.

The goal is to be able to create many web components using @angular and then consuming them within other @angular or `insert framework here` technologies.

Comment: You might also find this question interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836552/1085483

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunatelly, concatination of bundles does not work here, b/c webpack is using a global variable. The variable created by the alpha-bundle would be overwritten by the variable of the beta-bundle.

You could rename this variable in the bundles or you could go with [1] and it's --single-bundle switch.

To get started, forget about what the readme says about externals. This is an further optimization technqiue, where the host, alpha and beta could share the same libs. This prevents you from loading Angular several times.

Perhaps, also my [blog series about Angular Elements](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/13/angular-elements-part-i-a-dynamic-dashboard-in-four-steps-with-web-components.aspx) is interesting for you [2].

Best wishes,
Manfred

[1] https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus

[2] https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/13/angular-elements-part-i-a-dynamic-dashboard-in-four-steps-with-web-components.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure where the --single-bundle switch exists, is it for angular or a webpack feature? A google search did not yield any relevant results. As far as the webpack variable, I'm assuming it is the webpackJsonp variable that was referenced in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23732. I've just now put post build scripts to rename this variable in each bundle to a "unique" name and I'm able to host two separately built and bundled angular web components in an angular project. I'll take a look at your blog post series! I was hoping with v7 we would have an official way to do this.

Comment: After posting, I realized that the --single-bundle switch exists on the ngx-build-plus lib.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, as I was digging into some very strange solutions (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35429). All I had to do is to add ngx-build-plus and use the --single-bundle option to be able to run 2 different external Angular Elements (v 10.1.2) on the same page. Thank you so much Manfred, I could not believe how easy it was to get this working :)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Manfred Steyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52956715/860099) advices and it works so I will develop here his answer by giving more detailed working example (based on my case - Angular 8, I do it on MacOs):

On your `alpha` web-commponent (which is separate angular project `<alpha>`) run following commands

```sh
npm install ngx-build-plus -S
ng update ngx-build-plus --force
ng add ngx-build-plus
ng g ngx-build-plus:wc-polyfill
ng g ngx-build-plus:externals
```

(this will create file `webpack.externals.js` in your main project directory) and then in `package.json` on key `scripts` I add/edit key:

```js
"build:alpha:externals": "ng build --output-hashing none --extra-webpack-config webpack.externals.js --prod --single-bundle true --project alpha && cat dist/alpha/polyfill-webcomp-es5.js dist/alpha/polyfills-es5.js dist/alpha/scripts.js dist/alpha/main-es5.js > dist/alpha.js"
```

and now I build web component by:

```sh
npm run build:alpha:externals
```

this will create file `dist/alpha.js` - in same way you build `beta.js` (in beta project) - and in your `host` you can add both to your `index.html` by

```html
<head>
...
  <script src="./assets/web-components/alpha.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./assets/web-components/beta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
</head>
```

and both should work at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I used angular custom builder to export the built angular bundle with unique namespace using custom webpack configuration for angular builder.

1. Install *@angular-builders/custom-webpack* package
2. Create custom webpack config file. eg. *extra-webpack.config.js*.

   ```
   module.exports = {
   output: {
       chunkLoadingGlobal: 'webpackChunkModuleName',
       library: 'ModuleName'
   }
   ```

Provide your application name or any unique name for the chunkLoadingGlobal & library.

*Note*: These properties are as per webpack 5 which is used in angular 12+. Please refer webpack documentation for older versions of webpack.

3. Use *@angular-builders/custom-webpack* as your builder in place of *@angular-devkit/build-angular* and add *customWebpackConfig* object in *angular.json*.

> ```
> "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
>     .....
>     "customWebpackConfig": {
>        "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
>         "mergeStrategies": {
>            "externals": "prepend"
>          }
>      }
> ```

4. Now when you run ng build, your application would be built using custom builder with custom webpack configuration. Similar configuration for other application exported as web components and multiple web components can be used in same container application without any error or namespace collisions/contamination.